# Remove url subfolder on codeigniter 3 using route

Tags: php, codeigniter

I manage my controller into subfolder for easy maintenance. They are looked like this :

```
controller
  -admin
     c_admin
  -super_admin
     c_sa
```

So in common url which is the case in localhost, it must : `localhost/app/admin/c_admin` and  `localhost/app/super_admin/c_sa`

how can I get them into like this : `localhost/app/admin/` and `localhost/app/sa/`

Thanks for the help, it so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on `config/routes.php`

```
  $route['admin/'] = "admin/c_admin";
  $route['sa/'] = "super_admin/c_sa";
```

You can also pass arguments like this-

```
$route['admin/(:num)/(:any)'] = "admin/c_admin/$1/$2";
```

where `(:num)` is used for only numeric value and `(:any)` is used for both numeric & character

Answer (score 0):

The following method worked for me:

If you try to access admin app of application folder directly like giving the URL 
 **localhost/app/admin/** then the root file index.php will throw an exception e.g

**"Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php"**

To overcome this issue try the following method:

Add the following code in **index.php**

```
// Applications handling
$mystring = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$app_names = '/(\badmin\b)|(\bsa\b)/i';
$app_name = null;
preg_match($app_names, $mystring, $app_name);

// if array emtpy then call the default app 'admin'
$app_name = (isset($app_name[0]))?$app_name[0]:'admin';  
// if value found sa then set the app name 'super_admin'    
$app_name = ($app_name === 'sa')?'super_admin':$app_name; 

$application_folder = "application/{$app_name}";
```

Then go to your 
 
**application/admin/config/routes.php** and add this route **$route['admin'] = 'controller-name';**

Same process for super_admin application
**application/super_admin/config/routes.php** and add this route **$route['sa'] = 'controller-name';**

Now try your route i hope it will target the correct application

- **localhost/app/admin/** and
- **localhost/app/sa/**

I hope this will overcome your issue.
If found any solution better then this please let know then.

Thanks